# How to get a decent recommendation letter?

Tags: mathematics, recommendation-letter

I am trying to ask one of my professors to write a recommendation letter for me, but he did not say yes directly, instead, he said he would be willing to talk with me to hear more about my plans.

I did not interact with him too often when I took his course(a PhD-level pure math course). But I did get an A in that course(I did bad in the midterm, but pretty well in the final). I think he is still hesitant as to whether to write me a letter or not. When I go talk to him, how can I persuade him?

I am certainly not expecting a strong letter from him. I think my background is okay(8+Phd-level courses all A or A+, 1 REU), but the problem is that he probably did not know much about me. So my plan is to take my list of schools and abstracts of advanced courses with me when I go meet him. Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: What do you need the letter for?

Comment: I would be hesitant if I have nothing extra to add beyond what's already indicated by your marks.

Comment: I need the letter for my Phd application. That is true, but is there any way that I can provide the professor more information so that he can take advantage of them?

Comment: Maybe you should just talk to him about your plans, and let him ask for the information he needs. On the other hand, if you don’t expect a strong letter from him, why do you want a letter from him?

Comment: I do not really have many options since it happens to be the case that most of the advanced courses where I did pretty great were taught by postdocs.

Comment: What's wrong with postdocs writing recommendations for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not interpret what he wrote as necessarily discouraging.  He may just want to get to know you better so he can write a better letter.

Just talk about yourself and your academic interests.  What has been your favorite course so far?  What did you like about it?  What would you like to do in the future?  Etc.

Comment: +1.  Also, if you asked him via email, he may just want to see if you care enough to put a bit more effort into your request.